# How to split filename into array( key => value ) in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach, explode

I have a generator that create PDF files like this:

[image]

and upload files into `./files/` folder on server.

I used below code to get array:

```
<?php 
$files = glob('files/*.{PDF,pdf}', GLOB_BRACE);
print_r($files);
```

**OutPut:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => files/035146-761326.PDF
    [1] => files/035150-710753.PDF
    [2] => files/035151-771208.PDF
    [3] => files/035153-718443.PDF
    [4] => files/035158-219299.PDF
    [5] => files/035159-667486.PDF
    [6] => files/035172-113022.PDF
    [7] => files/035180-482460.PDF
    [8] => files/035216-232840.PDF
)
```

now I wanna splite each file name to `user` and `password`. for example if i have file like this: 
 `035180-482460.PDF` 
 I should have:

```
file['user] = 035180;
file['password'] = 482460;
```

I know, I show `foreach (files as key => value)` and some stuff to split filename; but I don't know how can I do that? :(

Comment: You should give at least what you've tried!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [list](http://php.net/list) and [explode](http://php.net/explode):

```
<?php
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $base = basename($file);
    list ($user, $pass) = explode('-', substr($base, 0, strpos($base, '.')));
    // $user would contain 035146
    // $pass would contain 761326
}
```

First you get the [basename](http://php.net/basename) (convert `files/035146-761326.PDF` to `035146-761326.PDF`) then you'd use [substr](http://php.net/substr) and [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) to only return the file name excluding the extension, then explode using `-` and you get the two parts.

Comment: i have another problem with `files/035146-761326.PDF`.

Comment: how to remove `files/` ?

Comment: Basename returns the filename exluding any path, so it will remove that

Answer (score 4):

array_map is very helpful in such cases:

```
$files = array_map(function($name){
  preg_match('#(\d+)-(\d+)#', $name, $matches); //get user and password
  return array(
    'name' => $name,
    'user' => $matches[1],
    'password' => $matches[2]
  );
}, $files);

print_r($files);
```

Comment: Really nice example of anonymous functions in php!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<?php 
$files = glob('files/*.{PDF,pdf}', GLOB_BRACE);
print_r($files);
foreach($files as $file) { 
   $file = preg_replace('/\/(?=.*\/)/', ' ',  $file); // it will solve the ./files/ issue which you mentioned in comment
   //  suppose $file is files/035146-761326.PDF
   $arr = explode("/",$file); // it will give array( [0]=>files and [1]=> 035146-761326.PDF)
   $filename = explode(".",$arr[1]); // now split $arr[1] with dot, so will give new array array([0] => "035146-761326", [1] => "pdf")
   $arrname = explode("-",$filename[0]); // now split $filename[0] with - so it will give array ([0]=>035146 , [1] =>761326 )
   echo "username: ".$arrname[0];
   echo "password: ".$arrname[1];
}

?>
```

Comment: i have another problem with `files/035146-761326.PDF`
     
how to remove `./files/`?